# wait for a job finished to render component in vuejs

Tags: socket.io, vue.js

I have a component here, and I need first to make a request using socket.io :

```
<template>
    <h1>Don't show me before the socket's response</h1>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        beforeCreate: function() {
            let sessid = this.$cookie.get('sessid')
            this.$options.sockets.logout = (data) => {
                if (data.redirect) {
                    this.$router.push(data.redirect)    
                } else {
                    console.log('here, you can render the template')
                }
            }
            this.$socket.emit('logout', { sessid })
        }
    }
</script>
```

This code works, but it shows the template in browser for a quick moment, before the redirection happens.

I would like to know if there's a tick to wait the socket response for rendering the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [v-if](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html), when the socket response arrives, you can set a variable which can be used with v-if to not show the HTML, something like following:

```
<template>
    <h1 v-if="sockResp">Don't show me before the socket's response</h1>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: function() {
           return {
             sockResp: false
           }
        },
        beforeCreate: function() {
            let sessid = this.$cookie.get('sessid')
            this.$options.sockets.logout = (data) => {
                if (data.redirect) {
                    this.$router.push(data.redirect)    
                } else {
                    console.log('here, you can render the template')
                    this.sockResp = true 
                }
            }
            this.$socket.emit('logout', { sessid })
        }
    }
</script>
```